# How to convert bibtex text into latex format

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

How to convert bibtex text into latex format in yii2.

Input should be like this :-

```
@article{citeulike:10427248,
title = {Information-based detection of nonlinear Granger causality in
multivariate processes via a nonuniform embedding technique},
author = {Faes, Luca and Nollo, Giandomenico and Porta, Alberto},
journal = {Phys Rev E},
volume = {83},
pages = {051112},
year = {2011},
publisher = {American Physical Society},
}
```

This input should generate following output:

```
[1] Luca Faes, Giandomenico Nollo, and Alberto Porta. Information-
based detection of nonlinear granger causality in multivariate processes
via a nonuniform embedding technique. Phys Rev E, 83:051112, 2011
```

Is there any widget for this?